# Is it possible to close the ssh session without closing byobu or the window?

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, byobu

If I use byobu, `exit` only closes the current shell. And I have to close all the shells to terminate the session, which is terrible, because I want to keep all the shells, which is why I use byobu.

Another way is to directly close the window. But sometimes I just want to resume to my local computer.

Is it possible to close the session without disturbing byobu? Or should I always open a new tab/window for an SSH session with byobu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, of course.

You want to "detach" from your session.

You can use Byobu's hotkey, <kbd>F6</kbd>, or you can use the tmux escape sequence, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*